# Aws android SDK

Tags: android, aws-sdk

While integrating aws in  android project ,I am getting below

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

Comment: did you added play service post your build.gradle

Comment: Yes I have added the play service .gradle builds well without aws libs ..BT throws the above error on adding